# Real Time Monitoring System using .net

Tags: .net

Need to know the right way of accomplishing this task.

Task Description:

We need to develop the application which display the dashboard where data from various SQL DB is fetched from different servers and displayed. Now this need to happen real time we can have refresh time say 5 min.

Please refer the analogy so that it will help me to take the right path.

Here are some details, Just for your reference.

1)  How many servers? 
            This application may support around Max 100 servers.

2)  This Application will be used by Administrator to find the health of the SQL Server DB.

3) This will be build by 2 developers in approx 3 months time.

4) Refresh rate will be configurable as a Administrator option.
 5) This will be a Web Based application.

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: Why would you need a special architecture for this? Databases are made for fast querying.

Comment: Right , but we will be extending more functionality of dashboard by including Service online/offline details from various servers on the dashboard. Therefore was looking what is the best strategy that can be adopted to build this application.

Comment: you can probably just use caching if you find high latencies.

Comment: if this is not a place to asked this question of software development. Where this type of questions can be asked. We ask this questions so that experts can give there opinion and we will learn from that.

Comment: You do realize that there are a number of factors left out of this question.  How many servers, e.g. 5 or 2,000,000?  What statistics are you wanting to show?  Is this intended to be used by administrators to know how healthy servers are or executives wanting to know sales data going into a database?  Real time here is somewhat misleading if the data can be a few minutes old though this is part of what a BA would do.  Is the company planning on spending the next 5 years building this or 20 minutes?  Is this being done by 1 developer or a couple thousand?  Lots of context is missing here.

Comment: @JB King : Have answered most of your questions. Do you have any suggestion.Not looking for complete solutions just a Approach will give me a start. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Build a simple prototype that displays the stats of a couple of DB servers and see how hard this is.  "The health of the SQL server DB" is something to break down into specifics of how much data are you wanting to see in terms of tables, threads, processes, CPU, RAM, hard drive and network I/O bottlenecks.  Scaling it up would be your third hurdle I'd think as you have to get which data is most important and display everything meaningfully that could be tricky.  For example, do you just state a current utilization or do you add a little context to that?

Comment: Planning to attack one Task at a time starting with hard drive details like used space , free space and reserved space and then extended by adding more data areas.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the same in several projects, and I'm using...

- [ASP.NET MVC 4.5](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
- [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
- [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)
- [Bootstrap Framework](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

add ons

- [Yahoo Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)
- [TypeKit](https://typekit.com/)

result can be seen below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks at least you felt like answering this. Appreciated.

Comment: you have to realize that this Forum is merely for Developers that have an issue that are struggling, and 99% is code based. Soon you ask a generic question, most likely you question is to be closed as it does not fall into any StackOverflow category. There are other forums for this kind of questions, have you saw all Stack Exchange sister forums? How about http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?